# How can I use tpm in linux kernel

Tags: security, kernel, tpm

I want to use TPM (Trustd Platform Module) in linux kernel. But, trousers library is not able to kernel.

So, how can I use TPM in linux kernel?

I am already doing analysis Trousers library but it have some problem. And maybe it's a naive solution.

Is TPM have not kernel side TSS library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no in-kernel TSS and there never will be.

Inside the kernel you are able to access the device directly via the kernel's tpm subsystem. You can communicate with the TPM by means of low level TPM commands and some in-kernel functions.

Comment: Thx dude. :)
And now I uses low level TPM command with TPM driver.